# What is the difference between meta sites and main sites?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta

I have just installed the Stack Exchange Android app, and have been creating accounts on different sites on Stack Exchange.

I noticed that from the main sites, I can reach a "meta site". What is this meta site?

Note: this question is about **per-site meta**, not Meta Stack Exchange which is covered aleady in [How does Meta Stack Exchange work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-exchange-work?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: Yes, reading rules and documentation is really boring... But you won't become good at this game by ignoring them ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Meta sites are for meta-discussion about their respective sites.

In other words - https://meta.askubuntu.com is for discussing the Ask Ubuntu site, community and such.

https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/ is for discussing the Computer Science site, community and such.

Meta Stack Exchange acts as the meta site for the whole Stack Exchange network.